# How does one make a boost::lockfree::queue be dynamically resizing

Tags: c++, boost

The documentation for boost::lockfree::queue mentions that push can allocate more space if need be. However I can't for the life of me figure out how to instantiate such a queue and I can't find an example of it. All of the examples on boost's website are of fixed capacity.

This is the documentation I was looking at:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html

Answer (score 6):

The default is for the queue to be variable sized. This is controlled by the `typename ...Options` template parameter.

Further, there is a bug which in which the queue demands a statically set capacity, even when the queue is variable sized. This can be avoided by using the constructor that takes an initial capacity.

A variable sized queue can be instantiated as:

```
boost::lockfree::queue<T> newQueue(0);
// or equivalently:
boost::lockfree::queue<T, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<false> > newQueue(0);
```

A fixed sized queue must explicitly set the `fixed_sized` option to `true` or supply a size with the `boost::lockfree::capacity` option.

See the `Policies` section near the start of the documentation that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I feel like I must be confused about something though. If I instantiate a queue as you suggest here then it fails with an assertion "Assertion `has_capacity' failed." I can pass the constructor a size which doesn't hit that assertion but then it appears to behave in a fixed_size manner.

Comment: See my edit. I believe the assertion is invalid, (that is, it is a bug in Boost.Lockfree). The requirement should either be documented, or the assertion should be changed to also check that the queue is in fact fixed-sized.

Comment: I think the assert is fine. It asserts that there **must** be an initial capacity (either because it's fixed, **or** because it's passed at construction). So constructing a dynamically sized queue without initial capacity is illegal. Can you refer to the relevant bug report/discussion to support your claim that "there is a bug"?